# Trigger not working in my code

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

The problem is my trigger is not updating. I want my trigger to work even in bulk update so that is why I have a nested loop inside my function, because I need to get the parentId of the object (parentId is equal to record Id of the object). I am getting no error, it is just not updating. I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Your trigger is on `DE_Activity__c` but your class method is expecting `ApexTest__c`. Are you sure you're not getting an error when you try to deploy this to your sandbox (or production, or scratch) org? Has this code actually been deployed somewhere, or is it currently only on your local computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the query inside of a loop (which we'll get to later), I don't see too much wrong with the code you've provided outside of your trigger being on `DE_Activity__c` and your static class method working on `ApexTest__c`.

For purpose of providing *some* answer, I'll assume that's just a mistake on your part (some anonymization that wasn't done completely). Even if that's not the case, this answer shouldn't change too much.

You are passing `trigger.new` into `updateTimeInterval()`, and you're using that in your outer loop, so if there are any changes (and if you're not running into any governor limits, validation rules, or other exceptions) then they should be appearing on your records.

Sure, declaring `firstCheckingDateElapse` and `lastClosedDateElapse` outside of your outer loop means that you can accidentally use the history dates you found for a previous `ApexTest__c`, but that's an easy enough fix.

As this work is being done in a before context, it could simply be that you need to do a hard reload of the record detail page you're testing with.

Anyway, that aside, the query inside of a loop is problematic and it should be dealt with.

The typical way to deal with this would be the "aggregate-query-update" approach

```
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
Map<Id, List<ApexTest__History>> childRecordsByParentId = new Map<Id, List<ApexTest__History>>();

// aggregate ids for querying
for(ApexTest__c parent :apexTestList){
    parentIds.add(parent.Id);

    // This is also a fine time to prepare the map we'll use later
    childRecordsByParentId.put(parent.Id, new List<ApexTest__History>());
}

// query
for(ApexTest__History historyRec :[SELECT Id, Field, DataType, NewValue, OldValue, ParentId, CreatedDate FROM ApexTest__History WHERE ParentId IN :parentIds ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC]){
    // and populate data for later use
    childRecordsByParentId.get(historyRec.Id).add(historyRec);
}

// update (which happens to be implicit in this case)
for(ApexTest__c parent :apexTestList){
    // By preparing the related (child) data before this point, we've ensured
    //   that we have the information we need for each parent while still
    //   keeping the query outside of all loops
    
    // Declare these dates inside of your loop so you don't accidentally carry over
    //   date data from another parent record
    // No need to explicitly initialize these to null (they will be null unless otherwise
    //   initialized)
    Date firstCheckingDateElapse;
    Date lastClosedDateElapse;

    for(ApexTest__History historyRec :childRecordsByParentId.get(parent.Id)){
        // Since you're ordering history by created date ASC, the first instance of
        //   "Checking" you run into will be the earliest date.
        // No need to use a list here, just skip past this IF if this date has
        //   already been set
        if(aHist.NewValue == 'Checking' && firstCheckingDateElapse == null) {
            firstCheckingDateElapse = aHist.CreatedDate.date();           
        }

        // Since your two checks are mutually exclusive, it makes more sense to have
        //   this be an else if.
        // In a similar vein to the above, you'll automatically get the last date
        //   if you simply keep overwriting your variable (since histories are sorted).
        // No need for a list here either
        else if(aHist.NewValue == 'Closed') {
            lastClosedDateElapse = aHist.CreatedDate.date();
        }
    }

    // No need for any additional checks here
    // If we didn't find a given date, the field will just be set to null
    apT.firstCheckingDate__c = firstCheckingDateElapse;
    apT.lastClosedDate__c = lastClosedDateElapse;
}
```

That's 23 lines of code, if you remove all of the explanatory comments

There are some improvements that could be made here:

- You can add a filter to your history query so that you only get checking/closed records (probably a good idea, as it reduces the number of query rows you'd consume)
- You could do the work of finding the first/last dates in the loop that's currently populating childRecordsByParentId (and use 2 `Map<Id, Date>` instead of the `Map<Id, List<ApexTest__History>>`, which would avoid the need for any nested loops

It's worth mentioning that not all nested loops are evil. You just don't want to be performing queries (or DML) inside of a loop, and want to avoid situations like

```
for(all accounts){
    for(all opportunities){
        if(opp.AccountId = acct.Id){
            //do work
        }
    }
}
```

which would have the code in the inner loop execute N*M times (as opposed to only executing M times if you knew which child records are related to the current parent record *before* the inner loop, and then only looping over those).

Comment: You are right that it was just a typo mistake. But thanks for the detailed explanation.  Greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @kanelopi One more thing that I just remembered. Writing tests for things that use system fields and/or history records is difficult. You'd be wise to create a "selector" class (i.e. a single class that is responsible for handling _all_ queries for a particular SObject) for the `__History` SObject and use that in place of your history query (i.e. `[SELECT ... FROM X__History]` becomes `XHistorySelector.byParentIds(parentIds)`). The idea being that you can mock that class in unit tests and return mock history records.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code it should signal an error since the data type the trigger is working on 'DE_Activity__c' isn't the one expected in the ApexTestClass  'ApexTest__c'.

And concerning the ApexTestClass code you can avoid using soql query within the for loop, you risk reaching the governor limit for the number of soql query.
You can use the code:

```
trigger DeActivityTrigger on ApexTest__c (before update) {
if (trigger.isUpdate){
    ApexTestClass.updateTimeInterval(trigger.newMap.keyset());
}
```

}

and in the second part do:

```
 public class ApexTestClass{
public static void updateTimeInterval(Set<Id> ids) {               
    List<Date> listDateOfChecking = new List<Date>();
    List<Date> listDateOfClosed = new List<Date>();
   
    List<ApexTest__History>listaHist =[SELECT Id, firstCheckingDate__c, lastClosedDate__c, (SELECT Id,  Field, DataType, NewValue, OldValue, ParentId, CreatedDate FROM Histories) FROM ApexTest__History WHERE ParentId IN: ids ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 50 000];
 
            
 for(ApexTest__c apT : listaHist) {
        
         for(ApexTest__History aHist : apT.Histories){
            if(aHist.NewValue == 'Checking') {
                listDateOfChecking.add(aHist.CreatedDate.date());           
            } 
            if(aHist.NewValue == 'Closed') {
                listDateOfClosed.add(aHist.CreatedDate.date());
            }
        }

        // update fields of ApexTest__c object
        if(listDateOfChecking.size() > 0){
        apT.firstCheckingDate__c = listDateOfAwaiting.get(0);
       }

        if(listDateOfClosed.size() > 0){
        apT.lastClosedDate__c = listDateOfClosed.get(listDateOfClosed.size() - 1);}  

listDateOfChecking.clear();
        listDateOfClosed.clear();
    }  }
```

Comment: Since this is in a "before" trigger context and OP is modifying record instances in `trigger.new`, there is no DML update required (and that is the entire point of the "before" trigger context).

Comment: yes you are right i guest it should even give an error since the datatype for the trigger and the class method aren't thesame.

Comment: There are also some syntax and semantic errors in your suggested code. - `apT` is not defined. - you're updating history records instead of the parent record. - you're assuming that the two date lists are never empty (`get(0)` will throw an index out of bounds exception if it is empty) - gathered dates aren't separated per parent id

Comment: yes it's true he was trying to update the parent record so i will modify the code a bit by grouping the data using a Map then from there i will be able to solve the issue although it will make me  use nested loops again. but the get(0) will be executed only when the if is true so i don't think i'll get such an exception.